# Calculate the intersection of arrays with a threshold in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, intersection

Let's say I have following arrays:

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5];
$b = [1,3,4,5,6];
$c = [1,7,8,9,10];
$d = [1,2,3,4];
```

The intersection of those would be `$result = [1]`, which is easy enough. But what if I wanted the intersection of those with a minimum threshold of let's say 3? The threshold means I can skip one or more arrays from the intersection, as long as my resulting intersection has at least 3 elements, which in this case might result in:

```
$result = [1,3,4];
```

1, 3 and 4 are present in $a, $b and $d, but not in $c which is skipped because of the threshold. Is there an existing PHP class, algorithm or function with which I might accomplish this?

Comment: Build in feature - no. You need to write a bit here :)

Comment: what is size of arrays? do they have duplicates?  how many arrays do you have? basically you should count values and select those there count > 3

Comment: why `$c` should be skipped with the threshold of 3?

Comment: @Federkun I edited the post:
"The threshold means I can skip one or more arrays from the intersection, as long as my resulting intersection has at least 3 elements"

Comment: The biggest intersection with the smallest amount of arrays dropped from the intersection

Comment: What would be result for threshold = 4 or 5 in your example?

Comment: Of 4 it would be [1,2,3,4] ($a and $d) or [1,3,4,5] ($a and $b) depending on the algorithm, doesn't really matter. For 5 it would be just one of the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that we have to use combinations of an array. I have used combinations algorithm from this [great article](https://r.je/php-find-every-combination.html). Adjusting this algorithm we can write the following class:

```
class Intersections
{
    protected $arrays;
    private $arraysSize;

    public function __construct($arrays)
    {
        $this->arrays = $arrays;
        $this->arraysSize = count($arrays);
    }

    public function getByThreshold($threshold)
    {
        $intersections = $this->getAll();

        foreach ($intersections as $intersection) {
            if (count($intersection) >= $threshold) {
                return $intersection;
            }
        }   

        return null;
    }

    protected $intersections;
    public function getAll()
    {
        if (is_null($this->intersections)) {
            $this->generateIntersections();
        }

        return $this->intersections;
    }


    private function generateIntersections()
    {
        $this->generateCombinationsMasks();
        $this->generateCombinations();

        $combinationSize = $this->arraysSize;
        $intersectionSize = 0;

        foreach ($this->combinations as $combination) {
            $intersection = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $combination);

            if ($combinationSize > count($combination)) {
                $combinationSize = count($combination);
                $intersectionSize = 0;
            }

            if (count($intersection) > $intersectionSize) {
                $this->intersections[$combinationSize] = $intersection;
                $intersectionSize = count($intersection);
            }    
        }
    }

    private $combinationsMasks;
    private function generateCombinationsMasks()
    {
        $combinationsMasks = [];
        $totalNumberOfCombinations = pow(2, $this->arraysSize);

        for ($i = $totalNumberOfCombinations - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
            $combinationsMasks[] = str_pad(
                decbin($i), $this->arraysSize, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT
            );
        }

        usort($combinationsMasks, function ($a, $b) {
            return strcmp(strtr($b, ['']), strtr($a, ['']));
        });

        $this->combinationsMasks = array_slice(
            $combinationsMasks, 0, -$this->arraysSize
        );
    }

    private $combinations;
    private function generateCombinations()
    {
        $this->combinations = array_map(function ($combinationMask) {
            return $this->generateCombination($combinationMask);
        }, $this->combinationsMasks);      
    }

    private function generateCombination($combinationMask)
    {
        $combination = [];
        foreach (str_split($combinationMask) as $key => $indicator) {
            if ($indicator) {
                $combination[] = $this->arrays[$key];
            }
        }

        return $combination;
    }
}
```

I have tried to give self-explanatory names to methods. Some chunks of code can be optimized more (for example, I call `count` function multiple times on same arrays; this was done in order to reduce variables fiddling) for production use.

So basically the logic is pretty simple. We generate all combinations of arrays and sort them decreasingly by the number of used arrays. Then we find the longest intersection for each length of combinations. Actually, this is the hardest part. To get one particular intersection we return first one that matches threshold.

```
$intersections = new Intersections([$a, $b, $c, $d]);

var_dump($intersections->getAll());
var_dump($intersections->getByThreshold(3));
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/188384ec693e32bacdea0de0ebdb410da6e8d946).

There are other ways to find all combinations, for example, [one from "PHP Cookbook"](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_25.htm). You can choose whatever one you like most.

Comment: @Jelle,  be aware, that I excluded, combinations of size 1 (array intersects with itself), as this is an edge case and you cannot pass one argument to array_intersect. So, be free to add it yourself. You can implement a method where add the array from `$arrays` with max length to the end of `$intersections` array with key `1`.

Answer (score 1):

No build in feature for that. You need to write something short like:

```
$values = [];

foreach ([$a, $b, $c, $d] as $arr)
    foreach ($arr as $value)
        $values[$value] = ($values[$value] ?? 0) + 1;

// For threshold of 3
$values = array_keys(array_filter($values, function($a) { return $a >= 3; }));
```

Note: This requires PHP7 for ?? operator. Otherwise use something like:

```
$values[$value] = empty($values[$value]) ? 1 : $values[$value] + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! that's a very elegant solution!

Comment: EDIT: I jumped the gun a bit: Wouldn't this give me an array of elements that occur in at least 3 of the arrays. That's not what I meant with the treshhold, I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: I think it's way more complicated to achieve that, cause they are other variables to consider. Like if you have same number of repeated elements in different combinations of arrays, which ones are to be excluded?